# Yaml value with a leading `!`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml

The Yaml parser for Ruby treats values with a leading bang as syntax errors (probably for shebang reasons?), so having something like this in a `database.yml` for Rails wouldn't be valid:

```
password: !something
```

How could I escape the exclamation point out? I've tried `\!something`, but that just includes the character. What's strange is the error I'm getting:

```
athan-$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/athan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:110:in `rescue in database_configuration': YAML syntax error occurred while parsing /home/athan/dev/AFC/AmericanFinancingMainWebsite/config/database.yml. Please note that YAML must be consistently indented using spaces. Tabs are not allowed. Error: (<unknown>): found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar at line 17 column 13 (RuntimeError)
    from /home/athan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:94:in `database_configuration'
```

Showing that `"\!foo"` doesn't actually escape the symbol. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not this?

```
password: '!something'
```